# getText always returns "" (empty) on onClick of button

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've been trying for two hours to fix this problem but I just can't. I've looked on StackOverflow and I tried fixing it by adding a viewInflater and setting the edittext in the onCreate() but nothing is doing it. So the problem is, even if I enter text in each fields String usernameS = txtUserName.getText().toString(); and the others always equals to "". I cannot find a solution. What am I missing here? Thanks

```
package com.awesometeam.liftm8;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.LightingColorFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.awesometeam.liftm8.data.User;


public class SignUpActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private UserDataSource m_DataSource;
    private View signupView;
    private EditText txtUserName,txtPassword,txtPhone,txtEmail,txtPasswordConfirmation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        Button btnSignUp = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        btnSignUp.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF));

        signupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_sign_up, null,false);

        txtUserName = (EditText) signupView.findViewById(R.id.txtNomUsager);
        txtPassword = (EditText) signupView.findViewById(R.id.txtMotPasse);
        txtPhone = (EditText) signupView.findViewById(R.id.txtTelephone);
        txtEmail = (EditText) signupView.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        txtPasswordConfirmation = (EditText) signupView.findViewById(R.id.txtMotPasseConfirmation);

        this.m_DataSource = new UserDataSource(this);
        this.m_DataSource.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        this.m_DataSource.open();
        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        this.m_DataSource.close();
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onClickInscription(View source) {

        String usernameS = txtUserName.getText().toString();
        String phoneS = txtPhone.getText().toString();
        String emailS = txtEmail.getText().toString();
        String passwordS = txtPassword.getText().toString();
        String passwordConfirmationS = txtPasswordConfirmation.getText().toString();

        if (usernameS.matches("") || phoneS.matches("")||
                emailS.matches("")|| passwordS.matches("")
                || passwordConfirmationS.matches("") ) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "All fields must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        else if (!(passwordS.matches(passwordConfirmationS))) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Both passwords aren't identical", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        else{
            m_DataSource.insert(new User(usernameS,passwordS,emailS,phoneS));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

My XML

```
<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
    android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
    android:onClick="onClickInscription"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTelephone"/>
```

Comment: Hum... Im a bit tired, but i dont see where you're setting the click listener.

Comment: Edited my post, the onClick is called in the XML. It goes into the function I've debugged it, it's just the Strings that are always empty. It always enters the first if.

Comment: In XML field 'onClick'

Comment: So you are absolutely sure you are filling every edit text with something?

Comment: Yes I've tried probably 50 times haha

Comment: Ah, lol, change matches("") to equal("").

Comment: Try to do all inside your `onClickInscription` function, like this : `txtusername = (EditText) source.findViewById(R.id.txtNomUsager); `and so on for all the EditText.

Comment: It changes nothing. It's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Change all string.matches("") to string.equals("").

Comment: Or to TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneS) and so on.

Comment: this doesn't change anything, the problem lies before the condition

Comment: Delete all `signupView= ...` and get the all EditText directly from your view that you has already put in `setContentView`

Comment: Like this : txtUserName = (EditText)finddViewById(R.id.txtNomUsager)

Comment: Oh my god Josef thanks so much it worked! If you want you can post what you just posted as an answer and upvote/accept as response.